# libpcap source and destination address are always NULL in captured ipheader.

Tags: c, linux, networking, libpcap

I've written a little program to play around with libpcap.
The problem is that the source and destination address fields of my captured header seem always to be nulls.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 65535

char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

void sniffloop(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);

void usage(char *name){
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <interface> <secret>", name);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pcap_t *sniffsess;
    struct bpf_program filter;

    if(argc<3){
        usage(argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if(!(sniffsess=pcap_open_live(argv[1], BUFFERSIZE, 0, 1000, errbuf))){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: couldn't open devices for sniffing: %s\n", argv[0], errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    if(pcap_datalink(sniffsess)!=DLT_EN10MB){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s not an ethernet device", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if(pcap_compile(sniffsess, &filter, "icmp", 0, 0)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: couldn't parse icmp filter", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if(pcap_setfilter(sniffsess, &filter)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: couldn't set icmp filter", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // daemonize here.
    pcap_loop(sniffsess, -1, sniffloop, NULL);
}

void sniffloop(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *hdr, const u_char *pkt){
    struct ethhdr *ehdr=(struct ethhdr *)pkt;
    struct iphdr *ipheader=(struct iphdr *)pkt+sizeof(struct ethhdr);
    struct icmphdr *icmpheader=(struct icmphdr*)pkt+sizeof(structethhdr)+ipheader->ihl*4;
    char *data=(char *)pkt+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+ipheader->ihl*4+sizeof(struct icmphdr);
    struct in_addr source,destination;
    source.s_addr=ipheader->saddr;
    destination.s_addr=ipheader->daddr;

    printf("sourceaddress is %p\ndestinationaddess is %p\n", ipheader->saddr, ipheader->daddr);
}
```

output:

```
spongebob code # ./icmpexec br0 foo
sourceaddress is (nil)
destinationaddess is (nil)
sourceaddress is (nil)
destinationaddess is (nil)
```

I've searched for an answer, but didn't find something.
I think it's most likely that I got some of the offsets in the protocolheaders wrong.

Thank you for looking over this! :D

Answer (score 2):

All your address computations are wrong. For example:

```
struct iphdr *ipheader=(struct iphdr *)pkt+sizeof(struct ethhdr);
```

needs to be:

```
struct iphdr *ipheader=(struct iphdr *)(pkt+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
```

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you for the hint. But what is the difference between these two statements? Isn't this just plain adding up of addresses+offsets?

Comment: @Hubert in the first statement you are adding an offset to (struct iphdr*)pkt. By the rules of C that means you are effectively getting the address of ((struct iphdr*)pkt)[sizeof(struct ethhdr)]. In other words the offset is multiplied by sizeof(struct iphdr). In the second case you are adding an offset to a (char *), so the offset is multiplied by sizeof(char), which is 1.